# NextJS default template with tailwinds isn't working

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

###### Sysinfo:

```
> Windows 11
> Node: v18.16.0
> Next: 13.4.13
> Tested Browser: Firefox, Chrome.
```

##### Step to Reproduce

---

##### I've generated a NextJS project with `npx create-next-app tezz` with this following options:

```
Would you like to use TypeScript? ... **No** / Yes
Would you like to use ESLint? ... **No** / Yes
Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? ... No / **Yes**
Would you like to use `src/` directory? ... **No** / Yes
Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) ... **No** / Yes
Would you like to customize the default import alias? ... **No** / Yes
Creating a new Next.js app in X:\web\tezz.

Using npm.

Initializing project with template: default-tw

Installing dependencies:
react
react-dom
next
tailwindcss
postcss
autoprefixer
```

##### When I run it and also tried to compile to production, the tailwinds isn't working properly (just work for the font, and some dark background), any other component like button isn't working and in the console is logged as follows:

```
> tezz@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
- event compiled client and server successfully in 322 ms (18 modules)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 288 ms (18 modules)
- wait compiling / (client and server)...
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...

warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
- event compiled client and server successfully in 3.8s (211 modules)
```

##### I know there's a warning about utility class, so there's the following `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

##### `./styles/globals.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  }
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}
```

##### `_app.js`

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

##### But, the magic is... when i change tailwind version to 3.1.8 everything is working fine, and if i switch to tailwind 3.2.0 and above, the css is messing.

###### There's the dependencies before changing the tailwind version:

```
"dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "next": "13.4.13",
    "postcss": "8.4.27",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  }
```

##### Attachment

---

*) This is the rendered page with tailwind 3.3.3
[image: not working pages]

*) This is the rendered page with tailwind 3.1.8
[image: working pages]

###### Any tips or advice would be awesome because I'm not really experienced with front-end stuff. xD

Changing the version of tailwind from 3.3.3 to 3.1.8 as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!
I think its just my windows environment, everything works fine on my linux env and docker